# How to create a custom Datasource in flink which will return a dataset?

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to create a custom data source to read a file from the Azure Data lake and create a data set with the content of the file and to sort the dataset. But flink is allowing to create only the Datastream not the data set. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Flink Batch also allows creating DataSet from your own data storage. Please refer to **ExecutionEnvironment**, there is a API named **createInput(InputFormat inputFormat)**, allowing to create customised data set.